# How to change the output resolution of a video without cropping it?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, transforms

I would like to change the resolution of the output video file to 1/4 of it's original size in both the X and Y directions.

But changing the pixel size in the dimensions part of the output properties tab just crops the video. I have also tried transforming the video to be scaled to 1/4 the size, but then the output is just an empty square of the original size, with the video at 1/4 the size in the center.

I would have thought that combining the two effects would enable me to rescale the video, by cropping the canvas size down to the rescaled video size. But unfortunately, cropping the output size also crops the transformed video, so that the fraction of space taken up by it remains the same. So the result is that I end up with a small square in the center, that only features a very small section of the lower left part of the original video.

I have been trying to find a solution to this, but have so far been unable to find any. Is there some way to make the scaling transformation permanent, so independent of any future change in the output dimensions? Or is it possible to have a different output compared to input size, that scales the video to match the size, rather than crop it?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try the beta version of 2.92. Just a few days ago, all of the vse transform functions were updated.